# acpi-call-dkms install fails with latest 5.8.0 mainline kernel

Tags: apt, kernel, 20.04, acpi, dkms

I have a new laptop (Lenovo IdeaPad 5 14ARE05 with a Ryzen 4000 SoC). In order for its hardware to be supported, I had to install the latest 5.8.0 mainline kernel on my fresh 20.04 Kubuntu install. However I also need acpi-call-dkms for controlling power saving features etc.. However, the install fails:

```
Unpacking acpi-call-dkms (1.1.0-5) ...
Setting up acpi-call-dkms (1.1.0-5) ...
Loading new acpi-call-1.1.0 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-050800-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-050800-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.0-050800-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-050800-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package acpi-call-dkms (--configure):
 installed acpi-call-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 acpi-call-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Basically it just says it's not supported. Is there some PPA where I can get a newer version of that package that is supported? Or (how) can I build that thing from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of that package will compile with newer Kernels. The easiest way to get a newer version is to switch to the Ubuntu 20.10 apt repositories and then retry the install. One should be aware that that will basically replace all packages with unstable software. You may be able to find a standalone deb package somewhere on the web which may or may not work. Otherwise, you can still build from source, as kanehekili suggested.

Answer (score 0):

acpi-call was supported until Ubuntu 16.04, but not any longer. And Thinkpads newer than TP 410 can't use the tp-smapi module, but the tpacpi.bat package - both relying on acpi-call, but:

Starting with kernel 4.17 tpacpi-bat gets superseded by a new, native kernel API called natacpi (contained in the ubiquitious kernel module thinkpad_acpi).

`tlp-stat -b` would lead you in the right direction, if you have it installed.

So you might be lucky and won't need it anymore.

Otherwise you'd have to get the source code and compile it against your current kernel.

Comment: I'll check it out. I hope that that native API offers some advantages, since most other distributions at least still offer the option of using acpi-call.

Comment: That is so. Manjaro and Arch are still supporting it..

Comment: Mainline kernel 4.14 is LTS and I'm using 4.14.188 without any problems. Would that still have what was yanked in 4.17?

Comment: On my Arch Thinkpad T410 I don't need acpi call, but it is an old model that uses tp-smapi... , a newer T460s uses acpi_call with kernel 4.19 LTS

Comment: My laptop unfortunately isn't supported. It's considered an IdeaPad, not a ThinkPad and I guess that matters somehow.